# Asymptotic formula for the number of connected graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

It can be shown that the set of graphs with $N$ vertices $G_N$ has cardinality:

\begin{equation}
\lvert G_N \rvert = 2^{N \choose 2} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Recently, I wondered how much bigger $\lvert G_N \rvert$ is compared to the number of graphs with $N$ vertices that are path-connected, $PC_N$.

If we denote the set of Hamiltonian paths by $H_N$ we can easily show that:

\begin{equation}
H_N \subset PC_N \tag{2}
\end{equation}

and by Stirling's approximation:

\begin{equation}
\lvert H_N \rvert = N! \sim \sqrt{2\pi N} \big(\frac{N}{e}\big)^N \tag{3}
\end{equation}

and therefore $\lvert PC_N \rvert$ must grow exponentially fast.

Now, I'm curious about asymptotic formulas for $\lvert PC_N \rvert$ and I'm fairly confident that for large $N$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\lvert PC_N \rvert}{\lvert G_N \rvert} \leq e^{-N} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

but I suspect that a proof for this statement would be fairly subtle.

**Note:** I didn't make use of a computer before formulating this hypothesis but in retrospect I should have analysed the connectivity of random graphs, as suggested by Olivier Fouquet. This would have given me more insight into the problem.

Comment: According to Example 11.15 in Flajolet and Sedgewick, *Analytic Combinatorics*, the number $K_n$ of labeled connected graphs on $n$ vertices satisfies $K_n=2^{{n\choose 2}}(1-2n2^{-n}+o(2^{-n}))$.

Comment: Number of connected labeled graphs with n nodes is tabulated, with many links and references, at http://oeis.org/A001187

Comment: It's Example II.15, not 11.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my hypothesis (4) was completely wrong. Besides Example II.15 in Flajolet and Sedgewick, Analytic Combinatorics pointed out by Richard Stanley, another useful reference is [*The Asymptotic Number of labeled
Connected Graphs with a Given
Number of Vertices and Edges*](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/BCM_Connected1.pdf).

Their demonstration is fairly technical and the main finding is that if $c(N,q)$ describes the number of connected labeled graphs with $N$ vertices and $q \leq {N \choose 2}$ edges we have:

\begin{equation}
c(N,q) \sim {{N \choose 2} \choose q}e^{-Ne^{-\frac{2q}{N}}}
\end{equation}

and since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{5N}{{N \choose 2}}=0$ for large $N$, due to the symmetry of binomial coefficients, we have:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{q=5N}^{{N \choose 2}}c(N,q) \sim \sum_{q=5N}^{{N \choose 2}} {{N \choose 2} \choose q} \sim 2^{{N \choose 2}}
\end{equation}

so for large $N$ almost all labeled graphs are connected.

**Remark:** Although I say that the paper is technical, I don't mean this in a bad way. It's full of interesting insights and contains clever methods that I haven't seen before.

#### Addendum:

Olivier Fouquet and lambda made very helpful remarks regarding random graphs. In particular, I would like to point out lambda's remark that:

> ...the Erdős–Rényi random graph model with edge probability 1/2 gives the
>   uniform distribution on labelled graphs

It follows that Olivier Fouquet is right that there exists a much simpler proof that almost all simple graphs are connected. The proof is as follows:

Let's first note that the Erdős–Rényi random graph model with edge probability 1/2 gives the uniform distribution on labelled graphs since for each pair of vertices they are either joined by an edge or not. It follows that given a graph with $N$ vertices the probability that any finite subset of $k$ vertices, $V \subset \{v_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\lvert V \rvert=k$, are joined to a common vertex $v_l \notin V$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
1 - {N \choose k}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^k} \big)^{N-k}
\end{equation}

Now, we would like to show that:

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}{N \choose k}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^k} \big)^{N-k}=0
\end{equation}

Let's first note that:

\begin{equation}
{N \choose k}=\frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!} \leq N^k
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\big(1-\frac{1}{2^k} \big)^{N-k} \propto \big(1-\frac{1}{2^k} \big)^N \sim e^{-\frac{N}{2^k}}
\end{equation}

and taking logarithms we find that for fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\ln N}{N} < \frac{1}{k2^k}
\end{equation}

so we may conclude that a simple graph is connected with probability 1.

Comment: "So for large $N$ almost all labeled graphs are connected" Surely that conclusion can be obtained in a much simpler way than with the full asymptotic.

Comment: @Olivier I'm curious about your statement as I have a growing interest in graph theory but I'm not a graph theorist. Might you know of an elementary demonstration?

Comment: I'm not a graph theorist either, but the statement seemed intuitive to me (it is quite hard for a large random graph not too be connected). Anyway, the article *The $k$‐Connectedness of Unlabelled Graph* by Walsh and Wright contains a much stronger statement.

Comment: Perhaps what isn't immediately obvious (at least it took me a little bit when I learned it) is that the Erdős–Rényi random graph model with edge probability 1/2 gives the uniform distribution on labelled graphs and so a statement about "almost all labelled graphs" in this sense _is_ directly equivalent to one about random graphs in the usual sense.

Comment: @lambda That makes sense now. As suggested by Olivier, an approach via random graphs might yield a much simpler demonstration that almost all simple graphs are connected without requiring the full asymptotic. I'm thinking about such a proof right now.

Comment: Combinatorics and overcounting is another way. There are N choose k ways to divide the vertex set into a disconnected set of size k and one of size N-k,  and the number of labeled graphs on the pair that are disconnected has 2 to a significantly smaller exponent than N choose 2, giving that disconnected graphs are fewer in number by a factor of about (2^(N-1))/N.  Gerhard "Simple Arguments Really Do Count" Paseman, 2019.07.01.

Comment: Incidentally, the proof is wrong. The probability of a particular $k$-set being disconnected from the rest is $2^{-k(N-k)}$.  Multiply by $\binom Nk$ for the number of $k$-sets, then sum over $k=1\ldots N-1$ (or $k=1\ldots N/2$ if you like).  You will see that the term for $k=1$ is easily the largest.